# How to modify Tiny MCE defaults values in table plug-in?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to change some default values while inserting table like style, border, no of col, no of rows etc. To achieve this I am trying to make changes in table plugin of Tiny MCE version 3.4.8 in the path `tiny_mce/plugins/table`. I have done changes in some files like table.js and table.html but I can't see the changes. Does anyone know how to achieve it? Am I missing some steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that if using the tinymce developer download that there are two kind of files. First there is `editor_plugin.js` second there is `editor_plugin_src.js` .
The first one gets loaded when you load the `tiny_mce.js` on your page; the second gets loaded if you load `tiny_mce_dev.js` on your page.